# Parsing error: ',' expected. with array map function

Tags: reactjs

this is very simple react code, but I cannot figure out why it's so mad at me for trying to do a map. I double check the closing brackets and that the key matches and I've tried adding semi colon all over and nothing happened, the error is "Parsing error: ',' expected." on my recipes object but everything checks out. Thanks for any help!
[image: Terminal screenshot of error]

```
import React from "react";

const RecipeCard = () => {
  const recipes = [
    {
      id: "recipe-id-1",
      name: "Tomato Soup",
      description: "Love red soup ",
      ingredient: [
        { name: "tomato", measurement: 3, unit: "cup" },
        { name: "water", measurement: 3, unit: "cup" },
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "recipe-id-2",
      name: "Potato Soup",
      description: "Love potato soup ",
      ingredient: [
        { name: "potato", measurement: 3, unit: "cup" },
        { name: "water", measurement: 3, unit: "cup" },
      ]
    }
  ];
  return (
    {recipes.map((recipe) => (
    <div className="recipeCard">
      <h2>{recipe.name}</h2>
      <p>{recipe.description}</p>
      <ul>
        {recipe.ingredient.map((ingredient) => (
          <li>
            {ingredient.name} - {ingredient.measurement}
            {ingredient.unit}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
    ))}
    )
  }

export default RecipeCard;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to group the content. use `</>` fragment

```
return (
    <>
     {recipes.map((recipe) => (
        <div className="recipeCard">
          <h2>{recipe.name}</h2>
          <p>{recipe.description}</p>
          <ul>
            {recipe.ingredient.map((ingredient) => (
              <li>
                {ingredient.name} - {ingredient.measurement}
                {ingredient.unit}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
        ))}
    </>
)
```

Comment: Yep that was it, thank you! I had tried that but I think I was missing a parenthese so it wasn't working at the time but cleaned stuff for the sake of this question and forgot to try fragment. Also doing the closing fragment with nodemon or something was weird in vscode it like kept adding the "</>" forever in my file(it was super weird to see it type itself). I had to stop all my server otherwise it kept adding the closing tag

Answer (score 0):

Do not use default export and wrap the output in a div:

```
import React from "react";

export const RecipeCard = () => {
  const recipes = [
    {
      id: "recipe-id-1",
      name: "Tomato Soup",
      description: "Love red soup ",
      ingredient: [
        { name: "tomato", measurement: 3, unit: "cup" },
        { name: "water", measurement: 3, unit: "cup" },
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "recipe-id-2",
      name: "Potato Soup",
      description: "Love potato soup ",
      ingredient: [
        { name: "potato", measurement: 3, unit: "cup" },
        { name: "water", measurement: 3, unit: "cup" },
      ]
    }
  ];

  return (
      <div>
        {recipes.map((recipe) => (
      <div className="recipeCard">
        <h2>{recipe.name}</h2>
        <p>{recipe.description}</p>
        <ul>
          {recipe.ingredient.map((ingredient) => (
            <li>
              {ingredient.name} - {ingredient.measurement}
              {ingredient.unit}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      ))}
      </div>
  )
    
  }
```